# Defining buttons in XAML for usercontrol

Tags: uwp, winui-3, winui

I am wanting to write a user control that contains a customizable `CommandBar`. There are standard items which are always present in the command bar, and the page hosting the user control can define additional items.

I have tried to implement it like this:

**User control**

```
        private ICommandBarElement[] _toolbarItems;

        public ICommandBarElement[] ToolbarItems
        {
            get => _toolbarItems;
            set
            {
                _toolbarItems = value;
                if (_toolbarItems.Length == 0)
                    removeToolbarItems();
                else
                    addToolbarItems();
            }
        }
```

**Hosting page**

```
        <local:HostControl x:Name="ctl">
            <local:HostControl.ToolbarItems>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Save" Content="Save" />
                <AppBarButton Icon="SaveLocal" Content="Save" />
                <AppBarButton Icon="AddFriend" Content="Friend" />
            </local:HostControl.ToolbarItems>
        </local:HostControl>
```

When I compile the application, compilation fails so I can't even debug. The error I get is

`Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

There is no line reference, but removing the `<local:HostControl.ToolbarItems>` node will cause it to compile, so the error must be how I'm defining the property in the user control.

How do I do it so I am able to define elements for the `CommandBar` inside of the host page xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a `DependencyProperty`.

**HostControl.xaml.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class HostControl : UserControl
{
    public HostControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += HostControl_Loaded;
    }

    private void HostControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.CommandBar.PrimaryCommands.Clear();

        foreach (var item in ToolbarItems)
        {
            this.CommandBar.PrimaryCommands.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public IList<ICommandBarElement> ToolbarItems
    {
        get { return (IList<ICommandBarElement>)GetValue(ToolbarItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ToolbarItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToolbarItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(ToolbarItems),
        typeof(IList<ICommandBarElement>),
        typeof(HostControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(new List<ICommandBarElement>());
}
```

Comment: Cheers Andrew. I already had the dependency property but omitted it, the issue was I was using an array. Changing to `IList` fixed it.